# Small Matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

I'm still getting used to matrix multiplication, and I'd like to make sure I'm doing this correctly.

my matrices are

$A =  
\begin{bmatrix} 1&2 \\  3&1 \end{bmatrix}$

$B =  
\begin{bmatrix} 2&0 \\  1&0 \end{bmatrix}$

The solution I came up with is

$C =  
\begin{bmatrix}4&0 \\  7&0 \end{bmatrix}$
I come to this conclusion, I did

$A1\cdot B1 = C1$
$A2 \cdot B3 = C2$
$A3 \cdot B2 = C3$
$A4 \cdot B4 = C4$

Is this calculation correct?

Comment: @Moo Thanks! I tried searching the documentation for mathjax but I didn't see anything pertaining to formatting matrices, but that Web site will definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put an example and perform multiplication with your matrices as areference:

$A =  
\begin{bmatrix} A1&A2 \\  A3&A4 \end{bmatrix}$

$B =  
\begin{bmatrix} B1&B2 \\  B3&B4 \end{bmatrix}$

$C =  
\begin{bmatrix} C1&C2 \\  C3&C4 \end{bmatrix}$

$$C1 = A1\cdot B1 + A2\cdot B3$$

$$C2 = A1 \cdot B2 + A2\cdot B4$$

$$C3 = A3 \cdot B1 + A4 \cdot B3$$

$$C4 = A3 \cdot B2 + A4\cdot B4$$

Comment: Very helpful chart. How were you able to get the matrices to look nice? I even looked through the mathjax documentation and couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference is helpful when learning the basics. There's also an answer dedicated to matrices.

Comment: I had seen that post but I just realized I didn't scroll enough to get to the matrices explanation. Thanks!